# How to reinitiate selectize options on 'onDropdownOpen' event

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

Good Day,

I was trying to clear out the options first on my selectize dropdown before adding new sets of options when the user opens the dropdown menu.

here's my code:

```
var selectx = $('#location_package').selectize({
    onDropdownOpen  : function(){
    console.log('opened');
    selectx[0].selectize().clearOptions();
    }
});
```

but I always get this error `Uncaught TypeError: selectx[0].selectize is not a function` but base on the previous example.. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186103/handling-dropdown-on-selectize) it is how he calls the function. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectx[0]` refer to `selectize` object and you should define it outside the function:

```js
   

$('#location_package').selectize({
  onDropdownOpen: callback
});

 var selectx = $('#location_package').selectize();

function callback() {
  console.log('opened');
  var select = selectx[0].selectize;
  select.clearOptions();
}
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks @pedram.. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hi @pedram .. yep it worked.. but I had fixed some typo like control and moved the selectx initialization below the  `$('#location_package').selectize({
  onDropdownOpen: callback
});` and it worked.. Thanks!

Comment: @melvnberd glad to help